# Component URL defined in target mapping does not match the URL retrieved from application index

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-fiori

I have activated some applications on Fiori launchpad for S4HANA, for example -Manage Purchase Order,Post Outgoing payments etc.

These application's tiles are showing on the launchpad ,but when I click on Post Outgoing payments tile,It is only shows the busy indicator(flower) on the screen. When I checked on the console, It is showing[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQSLK.jpg)

I am getting this console message with every app.Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in URL’s.
Your console log says:

```
Target mapping URL: /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/sakp_genericui
```

and:

```
Application index URL:
/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/sakp_gen_ui_s1/~A33B4ED42354B20C9DBBF59446~5
```

Please check, if the target mapping URL is referring to an existing SAPUI5 application.
Otherwise the target mapping needs to be corrected in the SAP Fiori launchpad designer.

Your console log also says:

```
A possible reason is that the component ID is not unique.
```

Please check, that the component id of all deployed SAPUI5 applications are system-wide unique and there are no duplicate id’s.
Otherwise you need to modify such a duplicate component id of your app in all files and folders of your project, to make it system-wide unique.
Finally you need to adjust the target mapping in the SAP Fiori Launchpad with the new unique component id.